# Supabase insert will not add row

Tags: next.js, supabase

Can anyone explain why I am unable to post to a particular table using supabase? I have several tables and do not have a problem with the rest, all the policies are the same so I highly doubt that it is an RLS issue. It's a simple table with 3 columns, id, user and artist. I must be missing something, I have tried Upsert, insert. Deleting the table and recreating it. What is weird is, If I add a row via supabase backend, I can delete the rows on the front end. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Is there a possibility that it is caused somewhere in next js as I'm using the experimental app version? It wouldn't explain why the rest of the tables are fine if so.

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const supabase = createClient();
  const { data } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
  const body = await request.json();
  const userId = data?.user?.id;
  console.log("-----------------------------", userId);
  try {
    const result = await supabase
      .from("favourite_artists")
      .insert([
        {
          user: userId,
          artist: body,
        },
      ])
      .select("*");
    console.log(result);

    return NextResponse.json({
      result,
      status: 201,
      message: "Artist added to favourites",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you [simulating](https://blog.mansueli.com/using-custom-claims-testing-rls-with-supabase#heading-testing-rls-policies) the RLS policies and tried to insert directly in SQL?

Comment: I can now add a row however, If I delete a row I am then unable to add a new row. I get a status 200 and not 201. To give you a better idea of how it should function. The request is a favourite button that adds an artist to the users favourites. The table is linked to the artist and user via their id's and an ID for the row is generated, allowing the user to delete the row.